# What is the use of Playgrounds in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-playground

Hi I'm a beginner for `Swift` language and now i want to learn more about `Playgrounds`.

And according to the limitations of `Playgrounds`, 
it does not support on-device execution and custom entitlements.

If there is no on-device execution then,

is it kind of just checking how our application works? (or)

is that just gives an overview of how the app looks? on its RHS.

Comment: What do u mean by on device execution ?

Comment: Swift playgrounds are very useful for answers to your future questions about swift.

Comment: @ArpitParekh: Its like connecting your device and you run the application on the device from the xcode...

Comment: @AntonBronnikov: yes i agree on that .. it helps in  understanding the basics much. But my qusetion is not that.

Comment: Well, that's the main use of playgrounds, that is, try things out, check syntax, runs tests, verify code path, etc.  Do you look for some specific use, whether it's possible or not?

Comment: No,What i'm trying to know is that when we add all our source files as frameworks inside a playground file then how can we see the kind of final output

Answer (score 4):

Swift playgrounds are interactive documents where Swift code is compiled and run live as you type. Results of operations are presented in a step-by-step timeline as they execute, and variables can be logged and inspected at any point. Playgrounds can be created within an existing Xcode project or as standalone bundles that run by themselves.

Playgrounds provide a great opportunity to document functions and library interfaces by showing syntax and live execution against real data sets. For the case of the collection functions, we’ve created the CollectionOperations.playground, which contains a list of these functions, all run against sample data that can be changed live.

Playgrounds allow you to edit the code listings and see the result immediately.

Comment: Awesome. I liked the point that we can create playgrounds in an exisiting xcode project. Lets give it a try..Thank you :)

Comment: @Sujania, did you manage to make it work so that playground code can used sources from the project?  The best approximation I got was by coping bits and pieces into source folder under playground, but that's quite cumbersome to do every time.

Answer (score 1):

Playgrounds do have support for showing UIViews but they are not interactive (with touches). So they are mostly used to test out algorithms and the look of your view.

However, they can also contain compiled code in the sources folder which is much faster than the code in the actual playground itself.

Answer (score 0):

Playgrounds are used for rapid prototyping of code snippets, and see the results in real time. As the name suggests, it’s a great way to “see” what your code is doing. Plus, according to the default comment by Apple, it’s a place to play! You do not need to wait for code to compile or make a new project and set it up just to check a small part of your code.

They can be used for :

- Documentation and testing
- Prototyping Accelerate — Optimized Signal Processing
- Rapid prototyping
- Making notebook type document to learn features with live results

Here are a few links for you to check:

[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start)

[General Details](http://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/rapid-prototyping-in-swift-playgrounds/)

[Apple WWDC 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY6nQS3MiF8)

[Apple WWDC 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr6QOU1Yg7w)